# Negative lookahead in regex to exclude percentage (%) in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I wish to extract numbers with any decimals (at least one number both sides of the decimal), but **not** patterns followed by percentages. Therefore, I believe I need a negative lookahead (so it can see if the number is followed by a percentage sign).

For clarity, I would want to extract `"123.123"`, but would not like to extract `"123.123%"`

I have tried a dozen syntax arrangements but cannot find the one that works. This successfully extracts the decimal pattern.

```
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d+")
```

But I want to adapt it to return the second item only (since the first contains a percentage sign.

I have tried various combinations of the following:

```
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d+(!?=%)")
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d+[!?%]")
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d+!?%")
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d+!?\\%")
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d+(!?=\\%)")
# etc
```

Comment: A negative lookahead would be `(?!%)`

Comment: How about `c("123.123%", "123.123")  %>% str_extract_all(., "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$")`

Comment: What about `x[!grepl("%", x, fixed = TRUE)]` ?

Comment: If the whole match is expected, `grep("^\\d+\\.\\d+$", x, value=TRUE)` will do. Why use `stringr::str_extract_all` then? Please provide real-life sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"\\d+\\.\\d++(?!%)"
```

The `\d++(?!%)` part matches 1 or more digits *possessively* and the `(?!%)` negative lookahead is executed once after all those digits are matched and fails the match if there is a `%` after them.

The same can be written without a possessive quantifier as `"\\d+\\.\\d+(?![%\\d])"`, where the `(?![%\\d])` will also fail the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

R demo:

```
> library(stringr)
> c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d++(?!%)")
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "123.123"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are we allowed to just use a stop character, if there is nothing else that can follow the number we may be okay.

```
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% str_extract_all(., "\\d+\\.\\d+$")
```

[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "123.123"

Answer (score 1):

We can fix with adding the `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the string in pattern

```
c("123.123%", "123.123") %>% 
      str_extract_all(., "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$")
```